# In text citation for reuse and permissions license

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing my thesis on Latex and some figures are copied from published manuscript. I have obtained the license to reprint these figures, but (if I understand correctly) I have to put the following credit line in the caption of each figure: "Reprinted with permission from <Full citation>, Copyright (YEAR) by the American Physical Society".

Here's the question, how do I make <Full citation> appear in text? I have that paper in bib file but "\cite" doesn't give me the full citation, just a number that references the bibliography (I used apsrev4-1 as my bibliographystyle).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/47927) that shows your problem? You don't need to give the real figures or the real citation, but something that we can work with and which makes us understand better the set up you have.

Comment: I removed the `biblatex` tag since you are using `apsrevs4-1` (which as RevTeX/`natbib` style is not compatible with `biblatex`).

Comment: With `natbib`/`apsrev4-1` the information you need to write the copyright notice is not available to citation commands. It is only printed in the bibliography. It might be possible to cook up something with `bibentry` and `usebib` ...

Answer (score 1):

The full citation will be that which appears in your bibliography, not the reference to the bibliographic entry. Copy the relevant details  and put them in the caption.

Comment: I can copy the details manually from bibliography sure, and it won't be too difficult for me since I am only doing this for a few images. However I am curious, are there ways I can ask bibtex to this using bib entries?

Comment: @TommyTsang I think that this is best treated as a new question by you. I have no idea about how to do what you have asked for.